# Error: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create failed: The scm url cannot be null

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, buildnumber-maven-plugin

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (default) on project common.model: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create failed: The scm url cannot be null.

Am getting above error when am trying to use buildnumber-maven-plugin to add build number in pom file after version.

I tried to used below plugin

````
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <format>{0,number}</format>
                <items>
                    <item>buildNumber</item>
                </items>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
        
            </configuration>
        </plugin>```
````

Comment: I would recommend to upgrade to the most recent version of the plugin https://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/ as the error message says your scm entries are not correct...